Cropping with Python and OpenCV to get passport ratio photos
I got the following python code that uses OpenCV to take a given picture and then look for a face and crop that face and save it with the word "Cropped" appended to the file name. Although it's working great, there's two things I cannot seem to figure out how to do.

It seems to be cropping very close to the face edges, I'd like to set an offset to convert it so that it fetches a passport like photo from the crop
It seems to also add a red border.

Can anyone kindly advise how I can possibly solve these two issues?
Thanks
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('testImage.jpg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml') 
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
   cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h),  
                 (0, 0, 255), 2) 
     
   faces = img[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
   cv2.imwrite('testImage-Cropped.jpg', faces) 

cv2.waitKey()


Please provide images

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cropping-with-python-and-opencv-to-get-passport-ratio-photos/18724


You need to remove the cv2.rectangle line, this is what adds the red rectangle around the face
Add some margin when cropping the faces, limit to valid indices, play around with the value of "margin" to find the one you like
cv2.waitKey() just hangs the execution, not sure why you need it
Note that you're overwriting the same file each time, i've added a counter so each face is saved in a different image file

The full example:
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('testImage.jpg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml') 
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
margin = 20
for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces):
   a = max(y - margin//2, 0)
   b = min(y + h + margin//2, img.shape[0])
   c = max(x - margin//2, 0)
   d = min(x + w + margin//2, img.shape[1])
   faces = img[a:b,  c:d] 
   cv2.imwrite(f'testImage-Cropped_{i}.jpg', faces) 

Edit: Per request I've added an example
original image:

source
collage of detected faces:

full code:
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('solvay-bw.jpeg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_cascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml') 
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
margin = 20
imface = []
w_max, h_max = 0, 0
for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(faces):
    a = max(y - margin//2, 0)
    b = min(y + h + margin//2, img.shape[0])
    c = max(x - margin//2, 0)
    d = min(x + w + margin//2, img.shape[1])
    face = img[a:b,  c:d]
    imface.append(face)
    w_max = max(b-a, w_max)
    h_max = max(d-c, h_max)
    cv2.imwrite(f'testImage-Cropped_{i}.jpg', face)

imdraw = np.zeros((h_max*4, int(w_max*np.ceil(len(faces)/4)), 3),     dtype=np.uint8)
imdraw[..., :] = (242, 248, 248)
for i, face in enumerate(imface):
    x = w_max*(i//4)
    y = h_max*(i%4)
    imdraw[y:y+face.shape[1], x:x+face.shape[0]] = face
cv2.imwrite(f'testImage-AllFaces.jpg', imdraw)


Your answer can be made better if you show us what the source image is, what the results are, etc...

This is a great explanation. Thank you. Right now it's cropping at an aspect ratio that makes the picture wider than taller. Is there a way to make it taller than the width like a passport photo sort of ratio?

give it some thought. you can do it. it's just a little bit of addition/subtraction. try it? the first step is reading Avico's code, understanding what it does. then you can adapt it. don't give up before you've begun.

@MarcusDeroy think about it, start with a larger margin and crop the image to fit the aspect ratio you want

@Avico thank you. What is the letter f before the file path on the last line cv2.imwrite(f'

@MarcusDeroy They're called f-strings, it's similar to printf in a sense. Here it's unnecessary, just something left from using f-strings for the previous call to imwrite. Shows the danger of duplicating and editing previous lines.
